# Key points and Importance of Decidability

Tags: computer-science, computation-theory, decidable

A language is decidable If a TM recognises the language and goes into an Accept or Reject state.  As a dev. I think this is important as it would mean we could determine if a program contains buffer overflows or deadlocks.  Also, the following problems are Un-Decidable:

- Does a program ever access an uninitialized variable.
- Do two context free grammars describe the same langauge.
- Does it make a difference if parameters to a subroutine are passed by reference or by copy-result

In terms of Decidability what would you say are the key points to Decidability and why is Decidability important (particularly to a developer).

Note: Bullet points are fine in answers - I can look up the topics myself.  I just want to know what are the main points.

Comment: Your first and third points are language dependent. In a language that simply does not allow variables to be uninitialized, it is of course perfectly decidable whether a program ever accesses uninitialized variables (the answer is always no). And even if it allows uninitialized variables in some situations, it might still be decidable (depending on what those situations are).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this belongs in the [cstheory exchange](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/), but I'll have a go at it anyway.

The key point is: some problems are undecidable, i.e. not solvable by an algorithm, so they should be tackled by other methods. Among these problems are many "meta-problems" concerning computer languages, for instance the problem of [detecting a virus](http://web.mit.edu/6.857/OldStuff/Fall01/handouts/L18-worms.ps).

Having determined that a problem is undecidable, there are several possible courses of action:

1. Some problems may be semi-decidable, i.e. there is a *semi*-algorithm that solves some cases, but loops forever on other cases. When implementing a semi-algorithm, put a timer on it and return `no answer` when the time runs out.
2. Solve only a few, hopefully crucial parts of the problem by simplifying it.
3. 2 + ask the user for input when the problem becomes too complex.
4. Use a heuristic that gets the correct answer *most* of the time.
5. Use a different language, perhaps a non-Turing complete one.

1 to 3 are popular for automated reasoning tools, including program verifiers. 4 is what virus scanners do. 5 is a [good choice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_%28mail_filtering_language%29) when allowing users to write scripts to automate a larger system; instead of giving them full JavaScript/Scheme/Lua/whatever, give them a restricted subset that does not allow unbounded recursion/loops.

Comment: +1 Great answer.  So knowing that a problem is undeciable would lead you to try different approaches.  But what would you say is the importance of decidability?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have to write some software that satisfies the condition: "at runtime no function shall ever end up calling itself directly or indirectly".

That condition would be undecidable, but a more restrictive condition may be decidable, for instance something like: "no function pointers shall be used and no function shall contain calls to itself directly or indirectly".

This is to highlight that sometimes it is possible to trade flexibility for decidability, so that certain required properties of the system may become enforceable.

If a programming language is decidable, then it will always be possible to decide whether a program is a valid program for that language or not.

But even if a program is a valid program for that language, it remains undecidable whether that program may incur a buffer overflow or a deadlock.